# action bar app unexpectedly closing

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My `ActionBar` app is closing unexpectedly. Please help me with it ...
I want to build action bar for 2.3 version I have add all support libraries also ...but  that giving unexpected closed message in android emulator.

main.xml code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Location Found -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:title="@string/action_location_found"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />



</menu>
```

and main_activity.java code:

```
    package com.jinesh.m_learning;

import android.app.Activity ;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html